# How to use future inside a list in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to load images from network and than passing it to [ExtendedRawImage](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_image/versions/0.2.3) as finished future `Image` to crop it.

The problem is that every new image that comes in uses (I think) the same instance of future to check if image has been loaded and that's why it shows `CircularProgressIndicator` on every new image.

The things I have **tried** and **didn't solve** my problem:

- Adding key to the future,
- Move functionality to completely new `StatefulWidget` widget.

The code and gif I'm working with right now:

```dart
AnimatedList(
  key: _sListKey,
  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  controller: _sScrollCtrl,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
  initialItemCount: sData.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
    final vehicle = sData[index];
    final color = defaultRegions.contains(vehicle.region)
        ? Colors.grey
        : Colors.blue;
    return _dataContainer(
        vehicle, animation);
  },
)
```

```dart
class CropImage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Vehicle vehicle;

  CropImage({Key key, this.vehicle}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CropImageState createState() => _CropImageState();
}

class _CropImageState extends State<CropImage> {
  Future<ImageInfo> _imageInfo;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    NetworkImage image = NetworkImage(widget.vehicle.image);
    Completer<ImageInfo> completer = Completer();
    image
        .resolve(new ImageConfiguration())
        .addListener(ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
      completer.complete(info);
    }));

    _imageInfo = completer.future;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: widget.vehicle.vehicleRegion.width /
          widget.vehicle.vehicleRegion.height,
      child: FutureBuilder(
        // key: UniqueKey(),
        future: _imageInfo,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<ImageInfo> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ExtendedRawImage(
              image: snapshot.data.image,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              soucreRect: Rect.fromLTWH(
                widget.vehicle.vehicleRegion.x,
                widget.vehicle.vehicleRegion.y,
                widget.vehicle.vehicleRegion.width,
                widget.vehicle.vehicleRegion.height,
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE_1**: `_dataContainer()` contains `CropImage` widget that I have wrapped with regular Container. Also as a side note, I'm using websocket to pass data to the `AnimatedList` by inserting it in the top of the list using `_sListKey.currentState.insertItem(0)`.

**UPDATE_2** I think I have narrowed down a problem. If I use any kind of `FutureBuilder` inside `AnimatedList` (as showed below), it creates the same problem (adding a 'Key' or moving to an other `Statefull` widget doesn't solve the problem).

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: http.get(vehicle.image),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<http.Response> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      return Image.memory(snapshot.data.bodyBytes);
    } else {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  },
),
```

**UPDATE_3**: It seams that the core problem comes from `setState()` call. Because I'm using `weboskcet` to pass data to view, every time new data comes in, `setState()` is being called to notify the `AnimatedList` or `Listview` to reload the view, which forces the `FutureBuilder` to refresh. But knowing this doesn't solve my problem.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  ws.dataCallback = (vehicle, status) {
    switch (status) {
      case 0:
        setState(() {});
        break;
    }
  };
}
```

**NOTE**: As a request, created sample repository of my problem ([link to repo](https://github.com/mciekurs2/flutter_sample_project)).

Comment: Do you use latest version of this plugin? Have you tried other plugins for cropping?

Comment: @MikhailPonkin I have also tried [Image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) package to crop an image but it also created the same problem.

Comment: Would you consider sharing a sample project? It's kind of hard to follow the code pieces.

Comment: @GazihanAlankus I updated question with sample repository of my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the documentation of FutureBuilder: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateConfig, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

You can solve this problem by wrapping the FutureBuilder in your own StatefulWidget and calling fetchImage in e.g. initState and assigning it to a field.

EDIT: If all images still reload even though the loading is done inside the initState method, this must mean the State objects are being reinitialized. Given that you mention you add the item to the beginning, your problem might be related to the following issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21023#issuecomment-510950338. It's mentioned that ListView.builder does not support changes in the list as it uses the index for tracking. Although the issue is about ListView.builder, the AnimatedList doc mentions:

> This widget is similar to one created by [ListView.builder].

If your only requirement is to insert items to the top, you may consider adding items to the end and using a reverse shrinkWrap AnimatedList. A minimal example:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Example(),
    );
  }
}

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  List<Vehicle> vehicles = new List();
  GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
  Random rng = new Random();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: AnimatedList(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        reverse: true,
        key: listKey,
        initialItemCount: vehicles.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) => SizeTransition(
          axis: Axis.vertical,
          sizeFactor: animation,
          child: ListTile(
            title: WidgetWithFutureBuilder('${vehicles[index].name}'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            int id = rng.nextInt(5000);
            vehicles.add(new Vehicle(name: "Vehicle $id"));
            listKey.currentState.insertItem(vehicles.length - 1);
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WidgetWithFutureBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;

  WidgetWithFutureBuilder(this.name);

  @override
  _WidgetWithFutureBuilderState createState() =>
      _WidgetWithFutureBuilderState();
}

class _WidgetWithFutureBuilderState extends State<WidgetWithFutureBuilder> {
  Future<String> future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.future = Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => widget.name);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: future,
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state.hasData) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(state.data),
          );
        }
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
  }
}

class Vehicle {
  Vehicle({this.name});

  String name;
}
```

Comment: I have tried that before and got exactly same result.

Comment: Can you edit your example code to a minimal runnable one that shows the problem? It might be that the problem is not in the code snippets you provided, but in the surrounding code.

Comment: I updated code so that you can better understand the structure of my code. As a note, I'm using a weboscket to pass data to `AnimatedList` by inserting it in the top of the list.

Comment: @MārtiņšCiekurs I've edited my answer in response to your update, hope it helps in your situation!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked for me. Only one thing, how would you change your code so that on new data it would stay on top rather than need to scroll to top.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I don't know how to create unique instance of the Future but I probably know how to solve your problem.

You can use FadeInImage to sort this out. FadeInImage puts a place-holder image and it replaces with the actual network image once it is loaded. The place-holder image can be gif loading indicator.

```
Widget _imageView(BuildContext context, String imageUrl) {
    return FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
        placeholder:'assets/giphy.gif' ,
        image: imageUrl,
    );

}
```

More information is available [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/fading-in-images) and [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-widget-guide-fadeinimage-widget-in-5-mins-or-less-2659a9aa5bfd).

Comment: The problem is that I need to crop an image using ` ExtendedRawImage` or converting base64 to image. I can pass image as network url only if I'm possible to crop it at the same time. For how much testing I have done, I think it is a bug, because it is not possible to pass image from memory or `ExtendedRawImage` without refreshing all other images using any kind of list.

Comment: I think it should be still doable with FadeInImage if it accepts local path as a URL. We will have to check. In this case you can use the image param as something like - image : getProcessedImageUrl(imageUrl).